# Nuget package problems

Tags: c#, nuget, system.reflection

I am having never ending problems with Nuget.  However, to be clear, this doesnt happen on another PC.. only mine.

So one of my nuget packages pulls in `System.IO.FileSystem`.

```
<package id="System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
```

By default it pulls in version `4.0.1` but for some reason the library is expecting version `4.0.0.0` and this exception is thrown

> Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileLoadException' in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.IO.FileSystem, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Ok, so not great, but a Google turned up other people having problems so I added a binding redirect into my `App.config` and thus continues the madness...

So this doesnt work:

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

So I tried this, which also doesnt work:

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.1" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Can anyone help?

FYI I have this set in the project file

```
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
```

Comment: Following on from Gregg's post below, what is the exact error you are receiving when you add the `dependentAssembly` element to the App.config?. #4 in Gregg's comment turned out to be the cause of the Package-Hell which I stumbled across weeks ago.

Answer (score 2):

I don't yet have enough reputation to leave a comment, so I apologize, as this might not be an answer.
Since you mention "only on your machine", I don't think there's a problem with the Nuget package itself, so my 'answer' is focusing more on things relating to your environment/machine.

Have you verified if:

1. You are using a reference path for the DLL(s) in the package you're referring to?
   It could be that the reference path is using an old(er) version, that is looking for ver 4.0
2. Your bin\... folder(s) is still holding on to an old(er) version of the DLL(s)?
3. Your GAC is holding on to an old(er) version of the DLL(s)?
4. (less likely, since it seems to be only on your machine) Other packages or referenced DLLs in the project are still needing ver 4.0?